# Relative image path reference is not working in the data template of the wpf xceed busyindicator control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xceed

I have refer the image using relative path reference **("pack://application:,,,/Images/LoadingBlocks.gif")** as mentioned. But image not able to loaded while running the application.

if i give the absolute image path, which working fine. that is

**("C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\Images\LoadingBlocks.gif)**

*or*

**("....\Images\LoadingBlocks.gif")**

Please find my code snippet and sample then suggest your opinion for refer the image from the solution itself.

```
 <toolkit:BusyIndicator Name="BusyIndicator" Loaded="BusyIndicator_Loaded" DisplayAfter="0" IsBusy="False">
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <MediaElement MediaEnded="myGif_MediaEnded" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/LoadingBlocks.gif"  LoadedBehavior="Play">
                        <MediaElement.OpacityMask>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/LoadingBlocks.gif"/>
                        </MediaElement.OpacityMask>
                    </MediaElement>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>
        </toolkit:BusyIndicator.OverlayStyle>
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Style>
        </toolkit:BusyIndicator.ProgressBarStyle>
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
        </toolkit:BusyIndicator.Background>

    </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

**sample:** 
https://ufile.io/zdm6r

or

https://github.com/mathikp/LoadingIndicatorSample

Comment: Did you add the image as a resource?

Comment: As a note `..\Images\LoadingBlocks.gif` is a relative path, while `pack://application:,,,/Images/LoadingBlocks.gif` is a WPF Pack URI, and of course absolute. That said, what exactly isn't working? Does the MediaElement not show the GIF, or does the OpacityMask not work?

Comment: @Clemens both media element and opacity mask not working (i.e. gif  image not loading) if we given the image path as pack URI. so how to set image reference path using pack URI. I have attached sample can you please check it

Comment: Make sure the image file is located in a folder called Images in your Visual Studio project, and that its Build Action is set to Resource.

Comment: @Clemens I have set build action as Resource and also image placed in that mentioned(Images folder) location. But not working

Comment: @P.Manthe yes i have added image as Resource.

Comment: Did you try to include the Assemblyname like: pack://application:,,, **/WpfApplication2;component** /Images/LoadingBlocks.gif

Comment: @DanielW. Yes, I have tried that also. But not worked for me. I have resolved that issue by using gif animated behavior of  WPFAnimatedGif assembly. instead of media element control. Thanks for your suggestion.